# All of my pages have class "page--node-" on the body element. This doesn't seem right

Tags: theming

I'm trying to track down the source of some CSS issues I'm having on my site and I noticed that every page has class "page--node-" added to the `<body>` element. The theme hook suggestions seem to include `page__node__%`.

This looks weird. Is it supposed to be like this, or is there a problem in a theme hook suggestion generated somewhere? I'm using a subtheme of Zen 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Classes beginning with page generally come from drupal core in [template_preprocess_html()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7), which calls [theme_get_suggestions()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_get_suggestions/7) to do the heavy lifting.

That function makes a bunch of suggestions for the classes or template suggestions based on the path of the current page. The % is used as a wildcard for numeric arguments (in this case the node id).

Then back in template_preprocess_html() it passes the suggestions through [drupal_html_class()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_html_class/7), which in turn runs them though [drupal_clean_css_identifier()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_clean_css_identifier/7), which strips out characters not allowed in a class, including the %, so you get a class of page-node- (this seems like a bug but there is a use for it I will explain below).

This theme_get_suggestions() code is the same reason you have the template suggestion with the percent symbol.

This means you can affect all node pages by using the template name page--node--%.tpl.php.

That might not seem necessary because you also have page--node.tpl.php, however if you want a different template for the path /node than you do for individual node pages you need to use both page--node.tpl.php and page--node--%.tpl.php.

This same reason is why the unusual class is useful.
If you want to style the /node page differently from individual node pages you can style page--node differently from page--node-

I agree it is a silly looking class though with pretty limited (or maybe none) documentation.

Also, something I found after writing this that is useful is [How Drupal determines page theme hook suggestions based on path](https://drupal.org/node/1089656#path-based-page-theme-hook-suggestions), from the "Drupal 7 Template (Theme Hook) Suggestions" documentation page.